# Connect two free Heroku applications to wake at once

Tags: heroku

I need to wake the backend free Heroku app at the same time as my frontend Heroku app.

When I visit my frontend application running React it takes about 15 seconds to wake up but then another fifteen seconds after the first API call for my backend to wake up. Is there a way to link these two so they wake up at once? I know I could put a call to the backend on first load of my site but that would still take the backend longer to wake up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to link these two so they wake up at once?

No.